# extract values from a method Laravel

Tags: laravel, collections

I have to add columns to a collection based on a common key ...

```
$usersDatas = $users->each(function ($record) use ($timeData) {
    $times = array_first($timeData, function ($value, $key) use ($record) {
            return $value['id'] === $record['id'];
    });

    $record['totalTime'] = $times['totalTime'];
    $record['spendTime'] = $times['spendTime'];
    $record['remainingTime'] = $times['remainingTime'];
    var_dump($record);
 });
 dd($usersDatas);
```

the dd($records) inside gives me the right result ... but i can't extract the results outside...

the dd($records) gives me :

```
array:17 [▼
  "id" => 1
  "ua_id" => 351
  "grade_id" => 584
  "metier_id" => 18
  "nom" => "XXX"
  "prenom" => "XXX"
  "matricule" => "XXX"
  "email" => null
  "datenaissance" => "XXX"
  "casque" => null
  "created_at" => "2018-01-30 09:59:32"
  "updated_at" => "2018-01-30 09:59:32"
  "deleted_at" => null
  "totalTime" => 240
  "spendTime" => 0
  "remainingTime" => 0
]
```

While dd($usersDatas) gives me this :

```
0 => array:14 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "ua_id" => 351
    "grade_id" => 584
    "metier_id" => 18
    "nom" => "XXX"
    "prenom" => "XXX"
    "matricule" => "XXX"
    "email" => null
    "datenaissance" => "XXX"
    "casque" => null
    "created_at" => "2018-01-30 09:59:32"
    "updated_at" => "2018-01-30 09:59:32"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "pivot" => array:5 [▶]
```

the 3 last fields are missing...

```
"totalTime" => 240
"spendTime" => 0
"remainingTime" => 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use `$collection->map(function($item) { ... })` for this:

```
// we will simply override $users here with an updated collection
$users = $users->map(function ($record) use ($timeData) {
    $times = array_first($timeData, function ($value, $key) use ($record) {
        return $value['id'] === $record['id'];
    });

    $record['totalTime'] = $times['totalTime'];
    $record['spendTime'] = $times['spendTime'];
    $record['remainingTime'] = $times['remainingTime'];
    var_dump($record);
    return $record;
});
dd($users);
```

---

`$collection->each(function($item) { ... })` is indeed executing the function for each item, but without modifying the collection. This method can be used as replacement for `foreach ($collection as $item) { ... }`, e.g. when the callback function `function($item) { ... }` is defined somewhere else in the code.

Comment: I replaced my each by the map function ...Unfortunatelly gives me a "null" result...

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add `return $record;` inside the mapping!

Comment: Nevermind ! it helped me a lot ... i finally solved my issue with this !!